# How to add native library folder to existing project in Netbeans

Tags: java, native

I have some native files. I need to load those into my project. How can I do so in Netbeans?

I'm loading them with:

```
System.loadLibrary("SBXPCJavaProxy");
```

Comment: I've reformatted your post, please pay more attention to formatting, grammar, and readability next time, so users can quickly read your post and answer. (It took me three reads to actually understand exactly what was being said)

Comment: @hexafraction k could u please help me out.How to add native project libraries to the our project.

Comment: @hexafraction How to add native project libraries to the my current project

Comment: @hexafraction  ya i have added like this in vm options: -Djava.library.path="C:\Users\admin\Desktop\SBXPC_CORE_130330ú¿sdkú¬\SBXPCJavaProxy.dll". but still i am getting same error

Comment: @hexafraction I tried  its not working could u explain me where is problem i gave like    -Djava.library.path="D:\bioproject\SBXPCJavaProxy.dll"  my .dll file is in D:drive.

Comment: @hexafraction I tried its not working could u explain me where is problem i gave like -Djava.library.path="D:\bioproject\SBXPCJavaProxy.dll" my .dll file is in D:drive

Comment: Please do not address me with multiple comments. I've fixed your post. If I had known an answer, I *would have posted it*. Asking me does not help.

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty forward in Netbeans:

- Right click on the Project.
- Select Properties.
- Click on RUN.
- In VM Options **TYPE** `-Djava.library.path="[dir]"`.
- Press Ok.

Basically you give directions to the compiler in which folders to search for available packages.

Note that [dir] should be an absolute path to the folder containing your natives. For example, if your natives are in `C:\Natives` then [dir] should be `C:\Natives`.

Comment: Main is not web application this is only a java application

Comment: the same options apply both to web and desktop apps

Comment: ya k k i have added like that but still i am getting same exception please help me out i have added like that -Djava.library.path="D:\bioproject\SBXPCJavaProxy.dll"

Comment: Add the folder, not the file: `-Djava.library.path="D:\bioproject\"`. Then you can use `System.loadLibrary("SBXPCJavaProxy");` to load the library.

Comment: @Anubian Noob  ya i have added only directory but still i am getting same Exception could u tel me where i did mistake.

Comment: @ Anubian Noob  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: D:\bio-metric\SBXPC_CORE_130330\SBXPCJavaProxy.dll: Can't find dependent libraries.

Comment: I have added like this -Djava.library.path="D:\bio-metric\SBXPC_CORE_130330"