# Add native library to Neabeans REST project

Tags: java, rest, netbeans, acrcloud

I am developing a REST service that will work with ACRCloud, and for that I use the native library acrcloud_extr_tool, but when I call the service that will call ACRCloud, I have an error that appears:
(java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError) java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no acrcloud_extr_tool in java.library.path

I am working in the NetBeans IDE 8.2 and the REST service will be deployed on a TomCat server.
I found articles saying to add a link in the options for running the JVM but what I tried does not work ...

Does anyone know how to solve my problem?

Useful links:

[How to add native library folder to existing project in Netbeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23427089/how-to-add-native-library-folder-to-existing-project-in-netbeans)

[giving 'java.library.path' in netbeans for .dll/.so files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714785/giving-java-library-path-in-netbeans-for-dll-so-files/11898261)

Comment: I have a dll file (acrcloud_extr_tool.dll) that I'v placed in my lib folder in the project but nothing change

Comment: Can you add some of the links you have read to your question?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really experienced with ACR but for what I've seen, there is a Java SDK so why not trying to use it instead of the native one?
If you try it, the steps are quiet good described (Eclipse only sorry :/) in the Github Repo (https://github.com/acrcloud/acrcloud_sdk_java).
Pay attention that you will need to install it on your Tomcat Server (as well as the correct version of vcredist) too in order to use it after deploying (unfortunatly I didn't find the package on Maven but maybe I'm wrong)

And maybe the easiest solution, if you don't need to many uncommon features, would be to call the webservice directly through HTTP request ? (https://www.acrcloud.com/docs/acrcloud/demos/web-api/)

Comment: I use the acrcloud sdk but in the classes provided, there are references to native libs

how i did'nt see the solution by the HTTP request, i'm gonna try this !
Thank you ;)